# What kind of configuration is required, so that WKWebView able to render image files in AppGroup directory?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have the following HTML string. We want to render image from our app `AppGroup`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>This is title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><h1>This is title</h1></p>
        
        <div style="font-size: 0">
           <img src="file:///Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A7B89802-9C65-4512-85A7-51C4372172D0/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/14DA3695-BFAF-4096-9F54-2874FD8285C2/attachment/b16c714e-9bb5-4eaa-924e-e043a69088ea.jpeg" width="100%">
        </div>
        
        This is body text
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if we execute the following code

```
let html = ...
// wkWebView is WKWebView
wkWebView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Only text is rendered. The image is not rendered.

If I save the above text as HTML file, and open it manually using Safari browser, the image can be rendered without issue.

May I know, what kind of configuration is required, so that WKWebView able to render image files in AppGroup directory?

Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation `baseURL` is “ The base URL to use when the system resolves relative URLs within the HTML string”. So I would pass the path to the app group in that parameter and use relative URLs in your HTML.

Answer (score -1):

- This is cause of wrong image url, use below image url and check it's work fine.

Replace:--
"file:///Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A7B89802-9C65-4512-85A7-51C4372172D0/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/14DA3695-BFAF-4096-9F54-2874FD8285C2/attachment/b16c714e-9bb5-4eaa-924e-e043a69088ea.jpeg"

With :--
"https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"

```
let html =

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>This is title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><h1>This is title</h1></p>
    
    <div style="font-size: 0">
       <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" width="100%">
    </div>
    
    This is body text
</body>
</html>

webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```